# Should I denormalize in this situation?

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-optimization

I have two tables: `conversations` and `messages` where each conversation have many messages

```
Message: (id, conversation_id, text, inserted_at, ...)
Conversation: (id, user_id ...)
```

I want to dispaly a list of conversation and for each, I want to display the text and the timestamp of the most recently added message. I also want to sort these conversations descending with regards for the timestamp of the most recently added message (newest on top)

Currently, I calculate these though using the MAX function (below is the query generated by my ORM)

```
SELECT c0."id", MAX(m5."inserted_at"), 
        (SELECT data->>'text' FROM messages
        WHERE conversation_id = c0."id" AND type = 'message'
        ORDER BY inserted_at DESC
        LIMIT 1)
      , c4."unread_count", v6."name", v6."id", (SELECT array(
        SELECT type FROM tags
        WHERE conversation_id = c0."id")) FROM "conversations" AS c0 INNER JOIN "tags" AS t1 ON t1."conversation_id" = c0."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" AS m2 ON m2."conversation_id" = c0."id" INNER JOIN "conversation_users" AS c7 ON c7."conversation_id" = c0."id" INNER JOIN "users" AS u3 ON c7."user_id" = u3."id" INNER JOIN "conversation_users" AS c4 ON c4."conversation_id" = c0."id" INNER JOIN "messages" AS m5 ON m5."conversation_id" = c0."id" INNER JOIN "visitors" AS v6 ON v6."id" = c0."visitor_id" WHERE (t1."type" = $1) AND (NOT (m2."visitor_id" IS NULL)) AND (u3."id" = $2) AND (c4."user_id" = $3) GROUP BY c0."id", c4."unread_count", v6."id", v6."name" ORDER BY MAX(m5."inserted_at") DESC LIMIT 10
```

My question is, would it make more sense to just denormalize these values and save them directly on the conversation record everytime a new message is added?

It seems awefully expensive to perform 3 MAX on a has_many association (it takes 600ms with just 3000 messages)

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes? Side note: A NOSQL database is probably better suited for this use case.

Comment: I have the standard indexes on all foreign keys, and I also indexed the inserted_at field on the `messages` table.

Comment: I hope the index on `inserted_at` in `messages` has conversation id first in the index.

Comment: Yep i have a composite index on both

Comment: Could you post the explain/execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, Yes you have to do it !
Add a new field in your conversation table. You dernormalize, but the performance gain deserve it.

An other option, I don't know if it can match your requirements, is to store your messages in an xml or json field in your conversation table. of course I assume you dont do anything else than select messages from a conversation